# What computing resources are required to run a hidden service?

Tags: onion-services, web-hosting, server-administration

Beyond the resources required to run whatever additional server software, how much RAM / CPU overhead should a hidden service operator factor in when estimating requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you're doing. In practice, very little, especially if it is a low-traffic static web site.

I've run low-traffic static sites on a Raspberry Pi before.